# Neural Networks w/ Fixed Point Parameters

Tags: neural-network, fixed-point

Most neural networks are trained with floating point weights/biases.

Quantization methods exist to convert the weights from float to int, for deployment on smaller platforms.

Can you build neural networks from the ground up that constrain all parameters, and their updates to be integer arithmetic?

Could such networks achieve a good accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

(I know a bit about fixed-point and have only some rusty NN experience from the 90's so take what I have to say with a pinch of salt!)

The general answer is yes, but it depends on a number of factors.

Bear in mind that floating-point arithmetic is basically the combination of an integer significand with an integer exponent so it's all integer under the hood. The real question is: can you do it efficiently without floats?

Firstly, "good accuracy" is highly dependent on many factors. It's perfectly possible to perform integer operations that have higher granularity than floating-point. For example, 32-bit integers have 31 bits of mantissa while 32-bit floats effectively have only 24. So provided you do not require the added precision that floats give you near zero, it's all about the types that you choose. 16-bit -- or even 8-bit -- values might suffice for much of the processing.

Secondly, accumulating the inputs to a neuron has the issue that unless you know the maximum number of inputs to a node, you cannot be sure what the upper bound is on the values being accumulated. So effectively you must specify this limit at compile time.

Thirdly, the most complicated operation during the execution of a trained network is often the activation function. Again, you firstly have to think about what the range of values are within which you will be operating. You then need to implement the function without the aid of an FPU with all of the advanced mathematical functions it provides. One way to consider doing this is via lookup tables.

Finally, training involves measuring the error between values and that error can often be quite small. Here is where accuracy is a concern. If the differences you are measuring are too low, they will round down to zero and this may prevent progress. One solution is to increase the resolution of the value by providing more fractional digits.

One advantage that integers have over floating-point here is their even distribution. Where floating-point numbers lose accuracy as they increase in magnitude, integers maintain a constant precision. This means that if you are trying to measure very small differences in values that are close to 1, you should have no more trouble than you would if those values were as close to 0. The same is not true for floats.

It's possible to train a network with higher precision types than those used to run the network if training time is not the bottleneck. You might even be able to train the network using floating-point types and run it using lower-precision integers but you need to be aware of differences in behavior that these shortcuts will bring.

In short the problems involved are by no means insurmountable but you need to take on some of the mental effort that would normally be saved by using floating-point. However, especially if your hardware is physically constrained, this can be a hugely benneficial approach as floating-point arithmetic requires as much as 100 times more silicon and power than integer arithmetic.

Hope that helps.